# Testeo de modelo lineal en R

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning

Para testear una regresión lineal múltiple necesito eliminar una fila de mi data frame(una observacion) estimar el modelo con los datos y predecir el valor de Y con los datos de las variables independientes que borre. Algo de mi código es

```
df <- data.frame(regresion_agregada)
df$periodo <- c(1999:2017) 

for (i in 1999:2017 ) {

  dt = filter(df, periodo!=i)
  model = lm(data = dt,formula = y ~ xa+xb+xc)


}
```

¿Cómo puedo probar el objeto model con los valores de la observación eliminada en el loop, es decir con los valores del periodo i para xa, xb, xc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Samuel es adecuada, pero por dar más alternativas, puede ser de interés los ejemplos de validación cruzada en:
https://rubenfcasal.github.io/intror/programacion.html#aplicacion-validacion-cruzada

Hay que tener en cuenta también que si lo que nos interesa es el residuo de validación cruzada tradicional (leave-one-out, LOOCV), se pueden obtener directamente a partir del ajuste del modelo con todos los datos. De la ayuda de R (e.g. `?influence.measures`):
"For linear models, rstandard(*, type = "predictive") provides leave-one-out cross validation residuals, and the “PRESS” statistic (PREdictive Sum of Squares, the same as the CV score) of model model is
PRESS <- sum(rstandard(model, type="pred")^2)"

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacer uso de `predict.lm()` indicando el modelo y la data de testeo (en este caso se filtra la data que contenga sólo el periodo indicado). Agregué un `print()`para que veas en la consola los valores que obtienes.

Ojo que el objeto `model` que queda en tu environment al final de tu for loop es el último utilizado, es decir, sólo corresponde al último periodo (2017).

```r
for (i in 1999:2017) {

  dt = filter(df, periodo != i)
  model = lm(data = dt, formula = y ~ xa + xb + xc)

  pred = predict.lm(object = model, newdata = filter(df, periodo == i))
  print(paste("El modelo predice el valor", pred, "para el periodo", i))
}
```

Comment: me podes ayudar a comprender el ouput del loop, tira 18 predicciones por año y no logro comprender el resultado.